# Conda CMD Crashes Upon Theano Installation

Tags: anaconda, conda, theano

Here are all the lines that I used to install theano:

```
# Create env.
conda create --name PyMC3 python=3.6

# Activate
activate PyMC3

# update pip
python -m pip install --upgrade pip

# Install theano reqirements
conda install numpy scipy mkl-service libpython m2w64-toolchain

# Install theano
conda install theano pygpu
```

I have CUDA drivers installed, which I use for tensorflow in another environment.

At the end of the installation, the CMD closes itself. Then every time I type:

```
activate PyMC3
```

It also closes / crashes.

Answer (score 0):

At this time (March 14th of 2019), it seems like Theano doesn't support python 3.6, even though there is a conda package for it.

I used python 3.5 and it installs.